# Roles and permissions in php

Tags: php, mysql, authentication

I am making a menu, but I want to limit it to only some users with a specific permission can see it.

the query:

> **SELECT idpermission,userid FROM user_permissions WHERE userid = "U001"**

Result: User U001 has 3 permissions stored.

> ```
> idpermission,userid
>  IDP001,U001
>  IDP002,U001
>  IDP003,U001
> ```

I have 3 tables **(users,permissions and user_permissions)**, in **user_permissions** I store each permission of each user

```
Example:

Table

user | permission | user_permissions

result:

user: u001,carlos,carlos@...

permissions: IDP001 = book | IDP002 = create_book | IDP003 = edit_book | IDP004 = user | IDP005 = edit_user...

user_permissions:
IDP001,U001
IDP002,U001
IDP003,U001
IDP001,U002
IDP003,U002...
```

when i call the query

> ```
> while($sqlRow=$sqlPermissions->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC))
>  {
>    if ($sqlRow['idpermission'] == 'IDP001' || $sqlRow['idpermission'] == 'IDP002' || $sqlRow['idpermission'] == 'IDP003')
>      {
>         echo "user menu ";
>      }
>  }
> ```

but the result that appears to me is 3:

> **user menu user menu user menu**

You should only show me one, making only a comparison if you have such permission shows but shows nothing.

What I want to reach is that the user can have many permissions for different items on the menu, such as view, edit, create, delete, each one is a permission, and each item (user menu, books menu) is another permission.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use a pivot technique to gather all permissions for a single user and form a single row to fetch with pdo.

This way all expected columns are declared and you can use simple truthy/falsey conditional checks in your php for any of the permission settings.

So long as the userid exists in the table, you will have a fully populated row to access.  This will be clean, direct, efficient, and easy to maintain.

**Schema (MySQL v5.7)**

```
CREATE TABLE user_permissions ( 
  idpermission VARCHAR(20),
  userid VARCHAR(20)
);

INSERT INTO user_permissions VALUES
('IDP001', 'U001'),
('IDP002', 'U001'),
('IDP003', 'U001'),
('IDP001', 'U002'),
('IDP003', 'U002');
```

---

**Query #1**

```
SELECT MAX(IF(idpermission = 'IDP001', 1, 0)) AS book,
       MAX(IF(idpermission = 'IDP002', 1, 0)) AS create_book,
       MAX(IF(idpermission = 'IDP003', 1, 0)) AS edit_book,
       MAX(IF(idpermission = 'IDP004', 1, 0)) AS user,
       MAX(IF(idpermission = 'IDP005', 1, 0)) AS edit_user
FROM user_permissions
WHERE userid = 'U001'
GROUP BY userid;
```

Result set:

```
| book | create_book | edit_book | user | edit_user |
| ---- | ----------- | --------- | ---- | --------- |
| 1    | 1           | 1         | 0    | 0         |
```

---

[View on DB Fiddle](https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/akbjbGTSaMHPm6WvQgD6iK/0)

Comment: Thank you very much, I tried it and it turned out, I am conditioning it with if and it is going very well.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure if your question was lacking information, or I may have missed a point.

Your example uses **U001** as a user id. The `while` loop seems to be correct in showing three "user menu" echos as **U001** has permission to view **IDP001**, **IDP002**, and **IDP003**.

If however, you try viewing **U002**, considering **U002** does not have permission to view **IDP002**, and **IDP003**. You won't see three echos.

However, I'd approach this a little differently than you did.
Maybe this might make things simpler for you.

```
$userPermissions = array(
    'book'        => 1,
    'create_book' => 0,
    'edit_book'   => 0
);

$menuItems = array(
    'book' => 'View Booking',
    'create_book' => 'Create Booking',
    'edit_book' => 'Edit Booking'
);

foreach ($menuItems as $key => $value) {

    if ($userPermissions[$key]) {
        echo $value;
    }

}
```

In the above scenario, you can store `$userPermissions` as serialized in your database. Then, once it's needed, get it from the Database and using the foreach loop create a menu by echoing the values of `$menuItems` if the user has permission to view it.

Your table (from my example) may look something like this:

```
id | user_id | permissions
```